# Degenerate distribution on a sample space of n elements

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am reading the book *An Introduction to Quantum Stochastic Calculus* recently. And I met the following statement:

**In a sample space of n elementary outcomes in classical probability the set of all probability distributions is a convex set whose extreme points are precisely the n degenerate distributions.**

without any proof.

My first question is that I think there are infinite degenerate distributions rather than just n ones. My reason is given a random variable X which takes constant value c on the probability space we can get a degenerate distribution $P_X$. So as the constant c changes we will as many degenerate distributions as we want, why it has to be n?

My second question is that how do I calculate the extreme points of all the probability  distributions.

Any hints and solutions will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are speaking only in the context of this sample space where there are $n$ elementary outcomes, i.e. every distribution can be represented by a tuple $(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$, $p_i \ge 0$, and where $p_i$ represents the probability of the $i$th elementary outcome. In this sample space there are only $n$ degenerate distributions. In other sample spaces (e.g. infinite sample spaces like the real line) there will of course be many more degenerate distributions.

---

I've given a characterization of the space of probability distributions above. You can directly check that (a) the degenerate distributions satisfy the definition of being an extreme point, and (b) the non-degenerate distributions do not satisfy the definition of being an extreme point.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't notice it is a sample space of n elementary outcomes, I thought it is a sample space of n points.